# How to make Call to Controller JsonResult from AngularJS with parameters like jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <span>Username:</span><input type="text" id="username" />
    <span>Password:</span><input type="text" id="password" />
<input type="button" value="Call Angular" onclick="Login()" />
```

My Action:

```
    public JsonResult Login(string Username, string password)
    {
        //check authentication
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = true;
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I want to send 2 parameters (username and password) with this call to my JsonResult with angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Use $http service of angularjs and make ajax call.

```
 function Login(Username,password) {
    return $http.get(
        url+ "Login",{Username:Username,password:password})
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
}
```

Better try to convert your actionresult return type to jsonresult. To use the $http service you have to inject the same in controller.

```
app.controller("ControllerName", function ($scope,$http) {
         //Code
});
```

You should have defined app as

```
var app= angular.module('app', []);
```

Your html should be like below:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ControllerName">
    <span>Username:</span><input type="text" id="username" />
    <span>Password:</span><input type="text" id="password" />
    <input type="button" value="Call Angular" onclick="Login()" />
<div>
</div>
```

Better download angular from nuget of Visual Studio so that you can use full features of angullarjs.

Js file should be like this:

```
 var app= angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller("ControllerName", function ($scope,$http) {

   $scope.data = $scope.Login(Username,password);
             $scope.Login = function(Username,password) {
        return $http.get(
            url+ "Login",{Username:Username,password:password})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return data;
            }).error(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
    }
    });
```

Comment: It gives me: ReferenceError: $http is not defined
 
return $http.get(

Comment: you should actually inject the $http service in the controller. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have changed its return type to jsonresult but the error not solved, i am unable to understand where  i need to add your code app.controller....

Comment: You have controller and app for angulars rit? Can you please update your question with how you declared your app and controller. In my answer app refers to the angularjs app/module and ControllerName refers to the angularjs controller.

Comment: I have simply added angular library on my view <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script> and trying to call my controller function, nothing else.

Comment: I would suggest you to study some more in angular before using. You should have an app and controller in angular side so that you can use it. From where now you are now trying to call your MVC Controller function?

Comment: Simply, i want to replace my existing jquery ajax call with angular js call. my jquery ajax call is working currently. i just want to replace $.ajax with angular call.

Comment: I can understand your requirement. Simply in js file you cannot implement an angularjs app. You just need to have an angular application. Then you can have one or more controllers under that angular application. You have to refer the application as ng-app in your html and controller as ng-controller in your html. Try with a simple sample on angular js and then you can understand better. It is really simple.

Comment: Is it compulsory to remove jquery from vs to use angular? can i use angular in my vs2010 sp1. i have already installed mvc 3 and 4 in this.

Comment: You can have jquery as well as anglularjs. But it is advisable to use angular only. I have updated my answer.

Comment: i am using this now, is i am going right?: function Login() {
       var app= angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller("Home", function ($http) {
        return $http.get(
        url + "Login", { Username: Username, password: password })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    });
    }

Comment: getting an error: ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Comment: Updated answer. I would strongly recommend you to study angularjs before using. Please create any sample which is simple. Visit angularjs tutorials.